# Make footer go in flow with `position: absolute` section

Tags: css, html, css-position

I am new to CSS and I have a problem when I try to position my boxes with `position: absolute;`. My web page is entirely built with `position: absolute;` (I know that’s not a good way), but I want my footer to adapt to my section box.

#### CSS

```css
header{
    position: absolute;
    left: 125px;
    width: 1100px;
    height: 550px;
    background-image: url("../Imagenes/Convertidas/Principal.jpg");
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

aside{
    position: absolute;
    left: 125px;
    top: 560px;
    width: 230px;
}


section{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #C3FAE7;
    width: 560px;
    top: 570px;
    left: 380px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: #B3ABAB 0px 0px 100px;
}



#asideP{
    background-color: #E1E1E1;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: #B3ABAB 5px 5px 10px;
}

#asideM{
    position: absolute;
    left: 980px;
    top: 570px;
    width: 230px;
}

#aside{
    list-style-type: none;
}

a:link{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#7D2C2C;
}

a:visited{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#7D2C2C;
}

a:hover{
    color: blue;
}

footer{
    position: absolute;
    left: 250px;
    top: 950px;
    background-color: #CCDED7;
}
```

#### HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Turismo Hondarria</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/estilo.css"/>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Russo+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <a href="Index.html"><img src="../Imagenes/Menu/Escudo.gif"/></a>
        <nav id="principal">
            <ul>
                <li id="hondarribia"><a href="Hondarribia.html"><img src="../Imagenes/Menu/hondarribia.png"/></a></li>
                <li id="tiempo"><a href="El tiempo.html"><img src="../Imagenes/Menu/Tiempo.jpg"/></a></li>
                <li id="contacto"><a href="Contacto.html"><img src="../Imagenes/Menu/Contacto.jpg"/></a></li>
                <li id="facebook"><a href="Síguenos.html"><img src="../Imagenes/Menu/Facebook.gif"/></a></li>
                <li id="twitter"><a href="Síguenos.html"><img src="../Imagenes/Menu/twitter.png"/></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <nav id="barrios">
            <ul>
                <li id="partevieja"><a href="Parte Vieja.html"><img src="../Imagenes/Menu2/Parte Vieja.jpg"/></a></li>
                <li id="lamarina"><a href="La Marina.html"><img src="../Imagenes/Menu2/La Marina.jpg"/></a></li>
                <li id="paseobutron"><a href="Paseo Butrón.html"><img src="../Imagenes/Menu2/Paseo Butrón.jpg"/></a></li>
                <li id="puerto"><a href="Puerto.html"><img src="../Imagenes/Menu2/EL Puerto.jpg"/></a></li>
                <li id="playa"><a href="Playa.html"><img src="../Imagenes/Menu2/La Playa.jpg"/></a></li>
                <li id="jaizkibel"><a href="Jaizkibel.html"><img src="../Imagenes/Menu2/Jaizkibel.jpg"/></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <section>
        <article>
            Fuenterrabía (en euskera y oficialmente Hondarribia) es un municipio del País Vasco, España. Cuenta con una población de 16.464 habitantes según datos del INE para el año 2010 y está situado en el extremo noreste de la provincia de Guipúzcoa, a unos 20 km al este de la capital, San Sebastián, en la desembocadura del río Bidasoa, que hace de frontera natural con Hendaya (Francia).<br><br>
Es una localidad de carácter turístico y residencial. En ella se encuentra el Aeropuerto de San Sebastián, conocido por su ubicación también como Aeropuerto de Fuenterrabía.

        </article>
    </section>

    <aside = id = "asideP">
        <ul id="aside">
            <li><img src="../Imagenes/Aside/ico_lat_durmir.png"/><a href="donde alojarse.html">Dónde alojarse</a></li>
            <li><img src="../Imagenes/Aside/ico_lat_comer.png"/><a href="donde comer.html">Dónde comer</a></li>
            <li><img src="../Imagenes/Aside/ico_lat_facer.png"/><a href="que hacer.html">Qué hacer</a></li>
            <li><img src="../Imagenes/Aside/ico_lat_visitar.png"/><a href="que visitar.html">Qué visitar</a></li>
            <li><img src="../Imagenes/Aside/ico_lat_servizos.png"/><a href="servicios turísticos.html">Servicios turísticos</a></li>
            <li><img src="../Imagenes/Aside/ico_lat_marisco.png"/><a href="fiestas y eventos.html">Fiestas y eventos</a></li>
            <li><img src="../Imagenes/Aside/ico_lat_galeria.png"/><a href="galería multimedia.html">Galería multimedia</a></li>
            <li><img src="../Imagenes/Aside/ico_lat_infoLanzada.png"/><a href="historia.html">Historia</a></li>
            <li><img src="../Imagenes/Aside/ico_lat_ligazons.png"/><a href="datos de interes.html">Datos de interés</a></li>
        </ul>
    </aside>

    <aside id = "asideM">
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d5800.819204160533!2d-1.795668602152656!3d43.36845882996644!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1ses!2ses!4v1413221754661" width="240" height="200" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
    </aside>

    <footer>
        <span>2014. <a href="http://www.hondarribia.org/index.asp?idioma=es">Ayuntamiento de Hondarribia</a> • Oficina de Turismo • Plaza de Armas, 9 • T. 943 64 36 77 • turismo@bidasoa-activa.com</span>
    </footer>

</body>
```

My section is placed in the middle of the screen, where I put all my text. So I need to adapt my footer so it goes in flow with my section.

Thank you.

Comment: A code snippet would be much helpful.

Comment: could you add html, and could you add css of the footer

Comment: @emmanuel whats a code snippet, thx

Comment: a code snippet is: http://jsfiddle.net/ for example. add your code there and post link here. so we can see what happens, also if you know using position absolute is bad why do you use it? you can change this to a floating webpage in a matter of minutes

Comment: Here, I made [a JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xcrpy5t7/) of the code in this question. Though I wouldn’t call it a “code snippet”; it’s better called a “live demo” or just “a JSFiddle”. A “code snippet” is just a piece of code in the middle of other text; you have two code snippets in the question right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you'd like it to be the same width? Just stick a width on the footer if so.

This is the wrong way to build a site in all but 0.01% of situations. Seriously, use another method like floats or flexbox.

Comment: I am new to CSS, and when I realize that it was a bad technique it was already over. But As @Good van deen Bekerom said, I will make it float.